# U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR crashing my application

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, didselectrowatindexpath

This is the error I am reciving when I select a value from my UITableView

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR (string Motron, pattern 
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

This is the first time I have had an error like this.. I am receiving it in my tableview method **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** on the second line of code shown below

```
// This predicate restricts the filterDataArray to the related values of the selected index
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"MASTER",cell.textLabel.text];
            filterDataArray = [dataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I have logged out the array of dictionaries and this is what one of the dictionary values looks like.

```
{
        HASM = 1;
        ISM = 0;
        ISV = 0;
        MASTER = Merc;
        MANURE = 96;
    }
```

There are about 60 or 17 of these dictionaries in the array.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not correctly using predicate in this case, try this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"MASTER CONTAINS [c]%@", cell.textLabel.text];
filterDataArray = [dataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: with that code I was given this error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:***

Comment: May be filterDataArray  is empty and you are trying to get object from array at index 0. Provide more code, that follows after filtering

Comment: I just checked my predicate and for some reason its not adding the cell.textLabel.text to it.. so its just MASTER LIKE "

Comment: @HurkNburkS, so what you want to say? does your code work? :)

Comment: nope not working yet.. Still working on it but I know where the error is now.. I just dont understand why cell.textLabel.text is not passing its value across properly.